# App will install on emulators but not on my device

Tags: android, apk

So I'm making a simple movie list app where it parses the TMDB API for information.

I was able to install it on my phone earlier just fine, but after only making some fundamental changes I can't get it to install.

Here is the error I get in the "Run" log:

```
11/09 18:07:22: Launching app
$ adb push C:\Users\jeremy\AndroidStudioProjects\MoviesList\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk/data/local/tmp/com.jeremy.movieslist

$ adb shell pm install -t -r "/data/local/tmp/com.jeremy.movieslist"
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]

$ adb shell pm uninstall com.jeremy.movieslist
Unknown failure (at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697))
Error while Installing APK
```

Anyone know what could be going on here? I tried it on my Google Pixel XL and a Google Pixel, and this is what I get. But when putting it on any of the emulators, it will install instantly and run flawlessly.

Could I get some help with this, please?

I've tried disabling "Instant Run," tried refreshing all gradle projects, and doing a whole lot of googling. Nothing is working so far.

---

**UPDATE 1**

So I found something out. In my gradle I have this dependency:

```
compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
```

This is for IOUtils (Apache Commons IO) which makes it very easy to parse JSON urls.

This is what is causing it not to install. To test it I created a new project and the only thing I did was add this line to the gradle.

The app would not install on my phone.

Does anyone know what I can do to get this dependency working?

Answer (score 0):

First remove the apk(old one, if any) from your device, then do a clean and rebuild, try installing apk again.

Comment: Go to google play store in your device and remove it from your google account list of installed apps.

Comment: Well the phone is currently not installed on my phone (since it wont install), so it's not in any of the lists for installed apps. The app has also not been published to the play store at all. It's a pretty basic app yet at this point.